# Making python code compatible for working with 2.7 and 3.6+ versions- regarding Queue module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-import

I want to make some common code of mine working through `python2.7` and also `python3.6` versions.
In syntax manner it simply implies the following: converting prints to console of types: `print "hello"` to `print("hello")` which is acceptable in both versions.

The problem occurs only in one module import for Queue module.
In Python2.7: `from Queue import Queue`
In Python3.6: `from queue import Queue`

Trying to do something in the `import` section like:

```
try:  
    from Queue import Queue
except ImportError:
    from queue import Queue
```

Will work but its really not elegant and ugly, any ideas for making it more reasonable?

Comment: It's pretty elegant if you ask me. But if you're going to write more polyglot code, `six` will help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not actualy so bad practice and can be seen in quite a lot of python modules. When it comes to support of both Python2 and Python3, [six](https://pythonhosted.org/six/) module can be quite handy.

With six you can import queue like that.

```
from six.moves import queue
```

It will automatically proxy your import to the appropriate place depending on Python version.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the below:

```
import platform
if platform.python_version().startswith('2.7'):  
    from Queue import Queue
elif platform.python_version().startswith('3.6'):
    from queue import Queue
```

Comment: I see no change except adding `if else` instead of try except and another module, imagine you have a section of import ...... import.....
and then coming try: except clause or `if else`, both seems worse at the same level